# El nuevo color de la reputación la vuelve indistinguible

Tags: bug, estado-completado, barra-superior, diseño

El color del texto de la reputación ha cambiado a blanco y es muy dificil verlo

[image: no se ve]

Al parecer viene de `.top-bar .my-profile .-rep`

[image: elementos]

Si deriva de los nuevos temas de la red yo lo consideraría un bug ya que es esto vuelve casi imposible ver nuestros puntos imaginarios de internet (la reputación)

---

Al parecer afecta a los demas sitios de Stack Overflow en diferentes idiomas, he creado un [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311574/new-reputation-color-makes-it-very-hard-to-read-on-stack-overflow-in-other-langu) en [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Otros sitios de la red como [webapps.se] usan negro como color de fondo, el lugar de aplicar el estilo de SO se están aplicando el de los sitios NO-SO

Comment: Exacto, eso me llevó a pensar que es algo relacionado con los _themes_ que están implementando, vi que los SO en otros idiomas tienen los mismos colores que nosotros pero no pude confirmar que les pasa lo mismo porque no tengo cuentas ahí

Comment: Pasa lo mismo en [pt.so] en los otros no tengo cuenta.

Comment: Tal vez sería buena idea confirmarlo y crear un post en [meta.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta pregunta [se ha resuelto](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311603/296470) ya. La comparto aquí para el beneficio de la comunidad.